# Does a Devil's Trap stop demons getting into things like the Impala's trunk?

Tags: supernatural, demons

The Impala has a Devil's Trap drawn on the inside of the trunk. I know it has been used to transport demons from place to place when they have been captured and that it stops them from getting away. Does a Devil's Trap also stop demons getting into things like the trunk of the Impala or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

The effect of a [Devil's Trap](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=Devil%27s_trap) depends on it's usage. Drawn on the ground it will immobilize demons, so that they cannot leave. But drawn at doors or similar it prevents demons from entering.

> Devil's traps have been used not only to detain a demon, but are also drawn at entrances as a deterrent to prevent access to a building, room, or container.

The Impala's trunk isn't protected by a Devil's Trap as it must have been drawn on the outside. In episode [Blade Runners](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=9.16_Blade_Runners_%28transcript%29#ACT_FOUR) Sam mentiones that there is some warding spell on the Impala's trunk.

> DEAN: Abaddon's. Well, she's just one jump behind us. Guess she couldn't find Magnus' joint, either. What about the trunk?
>   SAM: Safe. Warding kept them out.

Comment: Exactly... There is WARDING, but that is different from a Devil's trap. They may be very similar overall.

Answer (score 0):

A devils trap traps demons. Any demon entering the area of the trap would be trapped on the spot. They can get into the trunk but not leave.